# Android — How to track bandwidth usage by application or process?

Tags: android, bandwidth, usage-statistics

I can track the overall bandwidth usage of Android device. I wanted to know if there is any method or way, maybe an API or class, that can help me track my bandwidth usage per application or process?

Reason for this question? I want to stop all those processes or applications that are using way too much bandwidth usage and draining the battery.

Comment: May I ask how did you get the overall bandwidth usage information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the methods in [`android.net.TrafficStats`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html), particularly `getUidRxBytes` and `getUidTxBytes`.